# Re: LUBUNTU Disco Dingo - Is there an easy way to adjust volume with mouse-wheel

Tags: lubuntu, volume-control, mouse-wheel

...especially when watching video through external monitor (i.e. some distance from laptop)?

I realize there are a couple of answers for this but they are beyond me, a relative beginner. Is there a simple way to do this, like we have Volumouse or X-Mouse Button Control with Windows?

Comment: If I hover my mouse over the Volume Control panel applet, my mouse-wheel adjusts the volume higher or lower.  If I click the mouse-wheel, the volume mutes & unmutes.  I'm using Lubuntu 19.10 though  (I don't have a 19.04 'up' to test there currently).  https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html?highlight=volume  in the manual

Answer (score 0):

If I hover my mouse over the Volume Control panel applet, my mouse-wheel adjusts the volume higher or lower. If I click the mouse-wheel, the volume mutes & un-mutes.

or from the [Lubuntu manual](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html?highlight=volume)

> In the system tray there there are multiple widgets. With the volume
>   applet you can change the volume by using the mouse-wheel with the
>   mouse over the speaker icon or left click the speaker icon and drag
>   the volume up and down. To mute the volume with the button at the
>   bottom of the volume meter or middle click on the volume applet.

https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html?highlight=volume

I tested this and it works in both Lubuntu 19.04 & 19.10.

Comment: For our second TV, I watch through my computer, extended to an older TV (as a monitor) via HDMI cable. Our provider allows for this, so we can watch live TV and recorded PVR via the local network. When I do this, it is entirely fullscreen, which makes for what you mention impractical (none of these controls show while fullscreen). What I need is instant volume control with the mouse-wheel, while watching fullscreen online TV.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the volume with the mouse wheel, I have made Volumouse for Linux as you wish with config's options.

Look at this :
https://github.com/pzim-devdata/volumouse :)